# Testing equality of proportions

Tags: categorical-data

I am comparing three proportions for age categories for categorical variables that have also categories.
I used Chi-square test but I found that SPSS gave me a note which is for example:
a. 2 cells (33.3%) have expected count less than 5. The minimum expected count is .23.

What is the solution>

Comment: [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25664/805) addressed this kind of issue, though you could also perhaps do a version of an exact test for your 2x3 chi-square.

Answer (score 2):

One of the assumptions of the chi-square test is that each cell should have an expected count of at least 5.  If you have cells with lower expected counts, then they can severely bias your chi-square statistic upward.

In your case, you should run Fisher's Exact Test instead of the traditional chi-square.  Fisher's test does not have this assumption.  Here is a video showing you how to run the test in SPSS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LynasIsG0xI